# Why are only questions allowed that are related to a specific, notable claim?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I now know [what a notable claim is](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim), but why are we only allowed to ask, if the question is [directly related to a specific, notable claim](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Let's say you live in a very small town and there's a new rumour about something and you don't find information on the internet to disprove it, shouldn't it be allowed to ask that question.

Comment: I think all the ground is covered there and it makes more sense to keep all related discussion in a single place.