# Would it be on topic to use skeptics.se when ever I have a question no other SE site would fit for?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, scope

I just asked my self: Imagine I come across a question which doesn't fit on any SE site. (What not happens often, but it happened 1 or 2 times so far...)

So when I phrase my question into a claim and make this claim public, and then ask about the correctness of that claim here, would that be ontopic?

(ethics aside, about publishing knowingly wrong claims)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim has to be notable.

So, if you are a presidential candidate, and your speculations are published in the newspaper, then this workaround may be very successful, but if all your have is a Twitter account with 3 followers, the question based on the claim will be closed because it fails to meet our [notability requirements](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim).

Comment: Next personal goal: becoming a presidential candidate, so I'm able to ask ANYTHING on SE :D

Comment: @Zaibis Do you have $5000+ to spare? http://www.fec.gov/ans/answers_candidate.shtml