# What happened to my Ken Bone question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question

I asked a question about Ken Bone and his newly acquired Internet fame, and whether Anderson Cooper, the moderator of the second presidential debate, intentionally selected Bone to ask the last question of the night.  But it seems the question is now deleted.

Is the question off-topic?  Even so, usually, I see questions get put on-hold rather than just flat-out deleted.

Are questions about Ken Bone somehow not allowed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The question was put on hold by me as not [notable](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim) (I certainly have no idea who "Ken Bone" is so it seemed not notable).

Subsequently this question was deleted by another mod with the following comment.

> Question about motivation. Not notable. False premise. (The last question was asked by Karl Becker.) Deleting.

I think you can still see your own deleted questions from a link in your profile (but I may be wrong).

Direct link to the question: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35444/was-ken-bone-purposely-picked-to-ask-the-last-question-of-the-second-presidentia

Comment: His may not have been the last question, but Ken Bone is certainly notable now: http://www.cnn.com/2016/10/10/politics/debate-ken-bone-staring-man-trnd/

Answer (score 2):

There is, of course, [no taboo](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/892/revisions) on Ken Bone questions.

Poor questions are normally placed "On Hold" to give both the original poster and other users an opportunity to make edits to the question to bring it up to the community standards, and rescue the question so it can be reopened.

I deleted this particular question, because it had practically zero chance of ever being rescued. There was no point in leaving it around to waste people's time on, when they could be fixing more salvageable questions.

The question was about the motivation of an individual. We can never know what Anderson Cooper was thinking, so [that is off-topic](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/978/23).

The question did not have any references to show that it was notable. [We require claims to be notable](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/883/23) for a number of reasons. We don't accept claims that are just idle speculations by the poster.

Most importantly, this question was based on a completely false premise. Cooper **did not pick Bone last**, so the rest of the question on his motivations (and magical powers to predict the random whims of the Internet) doesn't make sense.

I'd invite you to read the both the [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users), and in particular the [FAQ Entry on what makes a good question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/faq-what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question) to avoid having your questions need to be put on hold or require major edits by others others.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks!