# Should we give more exact definition on what can actually be asked?

Tags: discussion, scope

I know how this sound.

Say I saw a page like this

http://thegoodlordabove.com/god-talks-several-trump-supporters-need-safe-space/

And I asked whether God actually created the page.

The claim is definitely **notable**.

So if our definition of ask able question is "verification" of notable claims, that definition will be totally inadequate.

Perhaps we should change it to `notable claim with significant number of honest believers`?

I mean there aren't many people that think it's true and now we have a clear rule why that question is **NOT** okay.

Currently people asking that question is called trolling and I don't think it's fair.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is asking for a firmer definition of what we mean by a notable claim.

We have an [FAQ entry](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim) that addresses that.

The FAQ says:

> A claim is 'notable' when a significant number of people believe it is true.

which is very close to your suggestion - i.e. "significant number of honest believers" is part of the very definition of notability, so it doesn't need to be explicitly called out every time we use the term.

Also:

> Sometimes people say stuff they don't mean to be taken as a claim; e.g. as comedy or in fiction. The claim is only notable if people believe it to be true, or at the very least, if it is clear that the author of the statement intended people to believe it as true (in the real world).

So, to use your example, which is a satirical web-page, where a humorist pretends to be God to troll believers, but no-one believes the account is run by a supernatural being,  it is **not** a notable claim for the purposes of this site. That is appropriate - there is no reason to waste our time proving that the Facebook user "God" is not a supernatural being.