# Why is my goverment-whatsapp-eavesdrop question "subjective"?

Tags: discussion, flags

While I was previewing my question, I stopped because the system indicated that my question was probably "subjective". The title of my question under construction was:

> Do government organizations read your whatsapp messages without physical access to your phone?

Before I started typing the question, I was already surprised that it wasn't asked already on skeptics stackexchange. It seems like a perfect factual question to me. Maybe we don't know the answer, but that would make the question even more interesting as we should look for evidence and that should not make the question subjective imo.

Comment: Seems a fine question for the main site, however, be sure that it is a notable claim, that is, there's evidence that many people believe it.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @fredsbend here, IF there is a notable claim, it seems perfectly reasonable for our site.  I copy and pasted your title into the "Ask Question" section and I didn't get an alert.  Was the alert specifically blocking you from posting the question?

Comment: Having pressed the submit button, I now saw the warning that you received.  Note that this is a warning and not a hard stop of your question.  If your question conforms to the standards of the site (notable claim, etc) then I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question tripped this filter because it contained the word “your” in the title. (Yes, for real, that’s exactly what [triggered the filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4435/323179).) There’s no need to reword it though.

It seems like a factual question to me too and something unlikely to be closed as long as it has a [notable claim](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2506/37236).

(It may have been already [answered on another site](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/121968/256139), though.)

Comment: Oh my, was it that simple. By the way I think many people believe it because so many criminals use other messaging systems and seem to avoid whatsapp: it has been in the news several times that the police were able to read criminals's messages (in the context of some messaging system other than whatsapp). But the link seems to answer the question.

Comment: The first link points to Jeff Atwood's answer posted in 2009. Has the filter not changed since then and/or have new words/expressions been added?