# If it's a daft idea is the author no longer notable?

Tags: discussion, notability

On Skeptics there is currently a [question, whether the sun revolves round the earth](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/54051/can-we-determine-for-sure-if-the-sun-revolves-around-the-earth). This idea was floated by someone I never heard of, who is, apparently, a "notable source". Perfectly good question.

Now I have a thought; if someone seeming to be notable makes a statement which is patently daft - not necessarily this one, just anything so untrue that you wonder if it's a parody - does that person remain notable? Can somebody disqualify themselves from notability by their output?

Comment: Please don't change your question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically addressed by our FAQ question: [What is a 'notable' claim?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim/2507#2507)

On this site, we expect the *claim* to be widely believed. Notability is really a property of the claim, not the author.

However, this is difficult to demonstrate, so we allow a number of proxies - several people making the claim, or many people being exposed to the claim. That it was said by a "celebrity" (however unreliable) is considered enough to show that many people are exposed to the claim.

History shows that just because practiced skeptics can see through a claim immediately doesn't mean it will be obvious to everybody.

Answer (score 3):

The question concerns a claim by [Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Schneerson), who is unquestionably a notable source as a late leader of the Lubavitcher movement of Hasidic Jews. His writings are considered widely authoritative both in his own sect as well as (to a lesser extent) Judaism in general. He is as notable as Pope John Paul II, Patriarch Kirill, Joseph Smith, Mary Baker Eddy, David Koresh, Baháʼu'lláh, Gerald Gardner, or Isaac Bonewits. You may not have personally heard of all of these people, but they are (or were) notable religious leaders with wide recognition both among followers and among non-followers. All of these leaders have followers today who are likely to believe their statements or consider them authoritative.

Some time ago, I posted a [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/41031/36598) concerning a scientific claim made by Mary Baker Eddy, a 19th century religious leader (founder of the Christian Science movement), and the question has been positively received.

Answer (score 2):

Someone can be notable and known by a large part of the world even if we personally don't know of them and have never heard of them. What they are saying has no input on that and the site has answered many claims regardless of the idea being "daft" or not.

That is never a reason to discard something.

Comment: That wasn't quite what I asked.

Comment: @RedSonja And I am saying that neither of those facts has any bearing on something being notable or not. It doesn't matter if you know of them or what idea they are claiming.